# How to access NavigateToString property of a WebView in a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime

I've got a `ListView` which contains, among other things, a `WebView`. When a `ListViewItem` on this list is selected, I'd like to bind HTML to the `WebView` via the `NavigateToString` method.

The WebView needs be in the bound list (as it's tied to a list of items), and *must* use NavigateToString (as the HTML content is coming from code, and is not on the web)

Is there anyway to do this? If so, what's the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can add an attached behavior using either an attached dependency property or a [Behavior](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com) that you could bind a string to that will navigate to that string when the value changes (e.g. when it is first assigned).

The other problem could be though with how it performs. I would think of the WebView control as a browser window, so if you have a hundred items in your ListView you might not want to create a hundred IE windows for all of them. Even assuming you use the default VirtualizingStackPanel as the ItemsPanel of your ListView - this sounds like a source of many issues. I haven't tried that, so I might be wrong, but I would rather try parsing the html and formatting it for use in regular TextBlocks. For very basic html you could use the LinkedHtmlFragment extension of the WinRT XAML Toolkit with a RichTextBlock if all you have is plain text and links. For something more fancy you might need to do some coding yourself or use something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (though I am not sure if it supports WinRT yet).

Comment: Thanks. I got it working but even aside from performance concerns, the WebView doesn't stretch to accommodate it's contents so I'll need to use a TextBlock anyway!

Comment: This question is over a year old so I can't recall everything, but looking at old code I can see that I set a `Tag` and a `Loaded` event to the `WebView`. When the event fires, it finds the correct content via the `Tag` and loads it into the `WebView` using `NavigateToString`