# How do I bind HTML to a DataTemplate's WebView?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access NavigateToString property of a WebView in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676520/how-to-access-navigatetostring-property-of-a-webview-in-a-listview)

I have a list of items that use a DataTemplate for each items presented.  Within this template I have a Webview of static HTML taken from an API call.  The DataTemplate is similar to as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DetailedPostTemplate">
        <Grid Height="600" Width="600">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Votes" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OwnerName}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <!-- HTML Content Row -->

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <WebView DataContext="{Binding Body}"/> <!-- What do I do HERE? -->
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

All I've been able to find, to 'pass' the data to the Webview is to use the `NavigateToString` method, but since I don't know the amount of items in the list, and I'm using a Template, I can't invoke this from the C# side of things.  How do I connect this HTML to the WebView using a XAML template?

Answer (score 2):

The `WebView` does not have a bindable property that supports this. There are a number of people that have written attached properties that allow you to bind to WPF and Silverlight `WebView` controls, these should work in Windows 8 with some small changes. See for example [this solution](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/binding-html-to-the-web-browser-control).